# Access to ArrayList<String> in Map in a different Class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a class Box, and in Box there is an `Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> smallBoxArr = new HashMap<>();`

If I want to store Strings in the smallBox, I use `put(boxId, "store String");`

Now in my Main Class, I want to get the length of a specific smallBox.

My code in Main:

```
Box box = new Box();
int boxId = 5;
System.out.println(box.smallBoxArr.get(boxId).size());
```

But I always get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you share the Box class ? Also It expects a List of string, you can pass a string

Comment: Either `box.smallBoxArr` is null, or `box.smallBoxArr.get(boxId)` returns null.